# Regex to skip certain characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a Regex which would skip characters like `<` & `>`. [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Now, to represent this I came across [this](http://regexone.com/lesson/4) `[^<>]` and tried using it in an console application, but it does not work.

```
[^<>]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SnpQS8b_opwyvGR1)

```
string value = "shubh<";
string regEx = "[^<>]";
Regex rx = new Regex(regEx);

if (rx.IsMatch(value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
}
else { Console.WriteLine("Fail"); }
Console.ReadLine();
```

The string 'shubh<' should get failed, but I am not sure why it passes the match. Am I doing something rubbish?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to only disable `<` & `>`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your question shows the answer: to match anything except `<` and `>`, the pattern `[^<>]` matches anything but those two characters. Again, what are you asking, since you already seem to know about this pattern?

Comment: Yep, Is that correct to implement? Thats what I wanted to confirm.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I have updated the question. I am trying in C# and this does not work. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Regex.IsMatch Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Indicates whether the regular expression specified in the Regex constructor finds a match in a specified input string.

`[^<>]` is found in `shubh<` (the `s`, the `h`, etc.).

You need to use the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^[^<>]*$");
if (rx.IsMatch(value)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

---

Another solution is to check if `<` or `>` is contained:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("[<>]");
if (rx.IsMatch(value)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
}
```

Comment: Feeling seriously guilty!!! :( How could I ignore that. Thanks for pointing that out.